# How to parse/decode JSON using Java from bufferReader output?

Tags: java, json, parsing, decode

I got a JSON output. Now need to parse the JSON String.

Some part of my code:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + query_en);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

How to parse the output using Java?

Comment: check the answer for the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: which json lib you have used?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of third party libs for parsing JSON in java. For example jackson:

```
private void test(BufferedReader reader) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(reader, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
        });
        System.out.println(map);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Gson:

```
    private void test2(BufferedReader r) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(r, type);
    System.out.println(myMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0 for that.

```
JsonObject jsonData = new JsonParser().parse(response.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
```